# How do I get the full MATE desktop after installing Ubuntu? mate-desktop-environment isn't complete

Tags: software-installation, mate

I've installed Ubuntu 15.04, and somewhere I read that I can install 'Mate desktop environment' on top of Ubuntu 15.04, but, this does not look like how I have anticipated, this Mate does not has the Mate tweaks which I was looking forward to. From my understanding, i've done completely different.

If I've understood it all wrong, what is the easy way to get the Ubuntu Mate 15.04 which I was talking about?

**Update:**

1. I've installed Ubuntu 15.04
2. Installed ubuntu mate using:

   sudo apt-get install mate-desktop-environment

This installed Mate on the ubuntu.

Comment: What did you do, exactly? And 15.04 is end-of-life, upgrade to 15.10.

Comment: @muru I've upated the question with more detail at the bottom

Comment: You probably should have installed [`ubuntu-mate-desktop`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/vivid/ubuntu-mate-desktop).

Comment: @muru how to install that, it looks like the full Mate that I need to install, but, not sure how to proceed from the website you have pointed me to, My apologies, i'm  noob on the linux distros

Comment: Just `apt-get install` it. The site I linked to is the package index, where you can search for packages to be used with `apt-get`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to get Ubuntu Mate the way you were talking about would probably just download it from https://ubuntu-mate.org/ and install it.

Comment: I agree, looks like this is the easiest way to do that.

Comment: spent like half hour and I have the Ubuntu Mate on my machine, super smooth. I was hating Ubuntu until now, but this one is good.

Answer (score 4):

The metapackages that correspond to the Ubuntu flavour are typically named `<flabour-name>-desktop` (`ubuntu-desktop`, `xubuntu-desktop`, `ubuntu-gnome-desktop`, etc.). These packages bring in the artwork, customization, etc., added to the base desktop environment (`gnome`, `xfce4`, etc.). In the case of Ubuntu Mate, the metapackage is [`ubuntu-mate-desktop`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/vivid/ubuntu-mate-desktop):

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-mate-desktop
```

Comment: I still do not see any difference after restarting the system. I ran this command and it installed about 180 mb. On the login it shows Ubuntu-mate with the green icon, but it when I login it is the same Mate

Comment: @Zeus Then you'll probably have to install Ubuntu MATE in a VM and compare. Can you list some features you were expecting but didn't find?

Comment: Would running `sudo apt-get purge ubuntu-mate-desktop` be enough to completely uninstall MATE desktop afterwards?